# Existing or Built In Scripts/functions to remove all comments in Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: java, oracle, performance, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I need to remove all single line and multi-line comments from an Oracle stored procedure.

I am expecting the below types of comments.

```
1. --

2. abc --

Multi Line Comments:

3. /*
    xxxx
    */

4. /*
    xxxx
    */insert into ...

5. insert into .../*
    xxxx
    */

6./*
    xxxx
    */--insert into ...

7. /*acct_rcvbl_acct_nbr, */

8. /*acct_rcvbl_acct_nbr, */insert into ...

9. /*acct_rcvbl_acct_nbr, */--insert into ...

10. /*acct_rcvbl_acct_nbr, */insert into ...;--acct_rcvbl_acct_nbr
```

Currently I am using normal java logic to remove the comments. Following the below steps to remove the comments.

1. Store SP text in a list order by
2. Remove all comments manually

The above process taking lot of time, impacting performance.

It would be very helpful if there is a built-in / designed stored procedure / script to remove the comments.

Comment: Text editors (such as Notepad++) allow you to search/replace using regular expressions, so - perhaps you could try with that. **However**, why would you want to remove comments? They are more than useful, especially for someone who inherits someone else's code and has no clue what it does and why is something written the way it is. With comments, it is a much easier task.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Need achieve this from java Program.